# When I change language at an astro.js page, it resets to homepage

Tags: javascript, internationalization, astrojs

When I change the language at an astro.js page it resets to the homepage instead of same page in a different language.

For example if I am on page `localhost:4321/en/about` and I change language to `hr`, it redirects me to `localhost:4321/hr`,  not to `localhost:4321/hr/about`

```js
import {
  ui,
  defaultLang,
  showDefaultLang,
  routes
} from './ui';
export function getLangFromUrl(url: URL) {
  const [, lang] = url.pathname.split('/');
  if (lang in ui) return lang as keyof typeof ui;
  return defaultLang;
}

export function useTranslations(lang: keyof typeof ui) {
  return function t(key: keyof typeof ui[typeof defaultLang]) {
    return ui[lang][key] || ui[defaultLang][key];
  }
}

export function useTranslatedPath(lang: keyof typeof ui) {
  return function translatePath(path: string, l: string = lang) {
    const pathName = path.replaceAll('/', '')
    const hasTranslation = defaultLang !== l && routes[l] !== undefined && routes[l][pathName] !==
      undefined
    const translatedPath = hasTranslation ? '/' + routes[l][pathName] : path

    return !showDefaultLang && l === defaultLang ? translatedPath : `/${l}${translatedPath}`
  }
}

export function getRouteFromUrl(url: URL): string | undefined {
  const pathname = new URL(url).pathname
  const parts = pathname?.split('/')
  const path = parts.pop() || parts.pop()

  if (path === undefined) {
    return undefined
  }

  const currentLang = getLangFromUrl(url);

  if (defaultLang === currentLang) {
    const route = Object.values(routes)[0];
    return route[path] !== undefined ? route[path] : undefined
  }

  const getKeyByValue = (obj: Record < string, string > , value: string): string | undefined => {
    return Object.keys(obj).find((key) => obj[key] === value)
  }

  const reversedKey = getKeyByValue(routes[currentLang], path)

  if (reversedKey !== undefined) {
    return reversedKey
  }

  return undefined
}
```